# AsyncHttpClient not working

Tags: java, android, android-async-http

I have the following timer in onCreate():

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

            public void run() {
                Log.i("EOH","timer");
                updateMarkers();
        }}, 0, 1000);
```

As you can see, it calls the function updateMarkers() every second.

Here is updateMarkers():

```
private void updateMarkers(){
        Log.i("EOH","updateMarkers()");
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.google_maps_marker);
        final MyItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,mapView);

        AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        final PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(context);
        myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("sw_lat", String.valueOf(centrePoint.getLat()-(Double.valueOf(mapView.getLatitudeSpan())/2.0)));
        params.put("sw_lng", String.valueOf(centrePoint.getLat()-(Double.valueOf(mapView.getLongitudeSpan())/2.0)));
        params.put("ne_lat", String.valueOf(centrePoint.getLat()+(Double.valueOf(mapView.getLatitudeSpan())/2.0)));
        params.put("ne_lng", String.valueOf(centrePoint.getLat()+(Double.valueOf(mapView.getLongitudeSpan())/2.0)));

        myClient.post("http://www.prestocab.com/ajax/getRanks.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            public void onStart() {
                thinger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i("EOH","onStart()");
            }


            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.i("EOH","xxx: "+response);
                thinger.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                try{
                    JSONArray arr=(JSONArray) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    Log.i("EOH","yyy: "+String.valueOf(arr.length()));
                }catch(JSONException e){

                }


            }


            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                thinger.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


            public void onFinish() {

            }

        });

    }
```

The problem I'm having is that `Log.i("EOH","onStart()");` never gets called! However `Log.i("EOH","updateMarkers()");` gets called...

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: can you paste your logcat from Log.i("EOH","timer"); getting printed to Log.i("EOH","onStart()");

Comment: onStart() doesn't get called... ;(

Comment: Yes, `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient`

Comment: The method in your `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` should have the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that current implementation of AsyncHttpClient - the first I start using - version 1.4.3 (2013-09-25) has some problem with local intranet hostnames. I was testing using a local network with the webserver running on my computer and it was calling onStart, but never calling onSuccess or any other methods.

My hostname was RM_UB02 (without the Internet domain suffixes). Android and Chrome web browsers were able to resolve the URL (http:// RM_UB02/test/page.html), but AsyncHttpClient never worked.

I changed to the local intranet IP address (192.168.1.104) and it started working.
I figured out that it was working all right for Internet names (http://slashdot.org ), but not for local networks.

Answer (score -3):

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
}

@Override
public void onFinish()
{
}

@Override
public void onSuccess()
{
}

@Override
public void onFailure()
{
}
```

Comment: And how does this fix the "AsyncHttpClient not working" problem?